# Adding FM to Rhythmbox doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, rhythmbox, gstreamer, internet-radio, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I'm trying to add a link into Rhythmbox Radio, and it says I need additional media codec, but I've already installed restricted-extra, even check through my installed list of package to see gstreamer-plugins were all installed. I can't find any relevant or up to date help on the web, please help.

[image: Error message in Rhythmbox]

```
~$ sudo apt list --installed | grep gst
[sudo] password for eanlee: 

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-alsa/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/bionic,now 3.0.26-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3/bionic,now 0.10.32.debian-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-gl/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-gtk3/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-libav/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-packagekit/bionic-updates,now 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.4 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-tools/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-vaapi/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-x/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libclutter-gst-3.0-0/bionic,now 3.0.26-1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-gl1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamermm-1.0-1/bionic,now 1.10.0+dfsg-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqgsttools-p1/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/bionic-updates,now 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
python3-gst-1.0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
synfigstudio/bionic,now 1.2.1-0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Edit:

```
~$ dpkg -l | grep rhythmbox
ii  gir1.2-rb-3.0:amd64                           3.4.2-4ubuntu1                               amd64        GObject introspection data for the rhythmbox music player
ii  librhythmbox-core10:amd64                     3.4.2-4ubuntu1                               amd64        support library for the rhythmbox music player
ii  rhythmbox                                     3.4.2-4ubuntu1                               amd64        music player and organizer for GNOME
ii  rhythmbox-data                                3.4.2-4ubuntu1                               all          data files for rhythmbox
ii  rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar          0.18.0-1                                     all          Enhanced play controls and interface for Rhythmbox
ii  rhythmbox-plugins                             3.4.2-4ubuntu1                               amd64        plugins for rhythmbox music player
```

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep rhythmbox` to the question. How did you got screenshot named *988 Properties* from rhythmbox?

Comment: The radio station name is 988, I used the add New Internet Radio Station in Rhythmbox to add in. Which the link is http://listen.988.com.my/
When I double click the added station, it requires me to install some additional multimedia codec, it opens up software center but found nothing.
Then when I right click that to see the properties, the screenshot is what I saw.

Comment: It seems that you messed FM (radio-waves in the air) and Internet radio (Shoutcast, Icecast and so on). For your information - you can listen Shoutcast radio stations using [*Guayadeque* media-player from `ppa:anonbeat/guayadeque`](https://launchpad.net/~anonbeat/+archive/ubuntu/guayadeque). I have never tested FM receiving in Ubuntu. I'll try your method and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link http://listen.988.com.my/ does not open in RhythmBox as it contains HTML document with JavaScript player.

So I found other one on http://www.radioonline.my - `http://starrfm.rastream.com/starrfm-988` .

I have added it to RhythmBox:

> [image: 988 FM - Basic]
>   [image: 988 FM - Details]

and it plays nice:

> [image: rhythmbox HUD]

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I should have thought of that it's not the proper link for Rhythmbox